# Can't Change Permissions of Files in Home Folder without Sudo

Tags: permissions, files, sudo

For some reason, I can't `chmod +x` files that are right in my home folder without prepending `sudo` to the command. 
One recent example: I have a file named `monitor-off.sh` in `~/Documents`. I tried to use this command at the terminal and received this message:

```
david@my-pc:~/Documents$ chmod +x ./monitor-off.sh
chmod: changing permissions of `./monitor-off.sh': Operation not permitted
```

However, when I prepended `sudo` to the beginning, it worked:

```
david@my-pc:~/Documents$ sudo chmod +x ./monitor-off.sh
david@my-pc:~/Documents$ ls -lh
total 28K
... (files) ...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root    44 Aug  8 15:32 monitor-off.sh
... (files) ...
```

I know that I shouldn't be overusing `sudo` like this, so what can I do to fix things so that I can use `chmod` without `sudo`?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `ls -l /home/david` and `ls -l /home/david/documents`? That will show us that you have correct permission to the folders. Also, you aren't perhaps creating these scripts with sudo, i.e. `sudo nano monitor-off.sh`, or `sudo wget http://somewebsite.com/monitor-off.sh`, right?

Comment: Oops, I meant `ls -ld /home/david` and `ls -ld /home/david/Documents`.

Comment: `david@my-pc:~$ ls -ld /home/david`

`drwxr-xr-x 28 david david 4096 Aug  9 08:57 /home/david`

`david@my-pc:~$ ls -ld /home/david/Documents`

`drwxr-xr-x 4 david david 4096 Aug  8 16:01 /home/david/Documents`

Comment: Gah, I can't make the line breaks appear.

Comment: Oh, just add them to the answer. I can see they are correct though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to be a permission issue. From the output i can see, that the file is owned by `root`. Only from the `root` account (but including with `sudo`) you can make changes to the file's permissions. You need the change the ownership of the file. Run this command in the Terminal to take ownership of *all* the files in your home directory:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
```

Comment: Hm, that's weird. I created those files in gedit running under my user account. Do you know how that could have happened? Both `/home/david` and `/home/david/Documents` are owned by me.

Comment: @EliahKagan  tried the command and root still has ownership for targeted folder, would this be affected if the folder(volume) is in a docker container? (Mac OSX)